# Open command console and pass arguments into it using VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ucanaccess

I have this:

```
Private Sub Command25_Click()

    Dim BatFile As String
    BatFile = "C:\UCanAccess-4.0.2-bin\console.bat"

    Shell BatFile & " " & """C:\Users\celso\Documents\KeysConsole.accdb"""
```

What I want is to use `UCanAccess` to connect to my database, with that above code it only opens the command console and wait for input arguments for directory of the database file.

How can I provide the argument so after console.bat is open pass the argument automatically and connect to the file without interaction.
Sorry I'm new on this and have tried different ways and no chances.

Answer (score 0):

The UCanAccess command-line utilities "console.bat" and "console.sh" are currently designed for interactive use only (as of version 4.0.2). They do not take parameters.